# Attach a method to a class while the class is being created

Tags: python, class, function, python-3.x

I've defined two classes as follows:

```
class ClassModel(object):
    pass

class FunctionModel(object):
    attr = None
    def __call__(self):
        return self.attr
```

The idea is to create several copy of `ClassModel`, each one containing zero or more methods inheriting from `FunctionModel`, which should have each one their own attributes.

I'm fine for creating children of `ClassModel` and `FunctionModel`. But I don't succeed to attach the two so that, when the children of `ClassModel` are instanciated, the function-like objects derived from `FunctionModel` which have been attached to them are recognized by Python as their methods.

See what happens

```
>>> func = type('func', (FunctionModel,), {'attr': 'someattr'})
>>> func_inst = func()
>>> func_inst
<__main__.func object at 0x968e4ac>
>>> Cls = type('Cls', (ClassModel,), {'func_inst': func_inst})
>>> cls_inst = Cls()
>>> cls_inst.func_inst
<__main__.func object at 0x968e4ac>
```

How can I go with this ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How exactly is this different from the desired behavior?

Comment: I is in that `func_inst` is an autonomous function, not a method of `cls_inst`, after the class has been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this. Class methods are added after the new class object is created (which is not exactly what I wanted), but before it is actually instanciated. Name of methods can be changed dynamically thanks to `setattr`.

```
class ClassModel(object):
    number = None

class FunctionModel(object):
    number = None
    def __call__(myself, clsself):
        return myself.number + clsself.number
```

Define the class and add it attributes:

```
from types import MethodType

func1 = type('func1', (FunctionModel,), {'number': 3})
func2 = type('func2', (FunctionModel,), {'number': 5})
func1_inst = func1()
func2_inst = func2()

Cls = type('Cls', (ClassModel,), {'number': 10})
setattr(Cls, 'func1', MethodType(func1_inst, Cls))
setattr(Cls, 'func2', MethodType(func2_inst, Cls))
```

And instanciate it:

```
cls_inst = Cls()
cls_inst.func1()
# 13
cls_inst.func2()
# 15
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using metaclasses, 
here an example:

```
class ClassModel(object):
    attr = None 

class FunctionModel(object):
    attr = None
    def __init__(self,aValue):
        self.attr = aValue
    def __call__(self, cls):
        return self.attr + cls.attr

def getFMClasses(aDictOfMethods): 
    class MM(type):
        def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):     
            for aName in aDictOfMethods: 
                dct[aName] = classmethod(FunctionModel(aDictOfMethods[aName]))
            return super(MM, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        pass                                                    
    pass                                                        
    return MM
```

Once all that is defined, getting new classes is a child game...

```
class NewClass1(ClassModel):
    __metaclass__ = getFMClasses({'method1':3,'method2':5})
    attr = 2 

class NewClass2(ClassModel):
    __metaclass__ = getFMClasses({'method1':6,'DifferentMethod':2,'OneMore':0})
    attr = 3 

myObj = NewClass1()
print myObj.method1()
print myObj.method2()
myObj = NewClass2()
print myObj.method1()
print myObj.DifferentMethod()
print myObj.OneMore()
```

Comment: This doesn't make `method1`, etc., methods of `NewClass1`, etc.

Comment: Then I edited, the relevant part is that I replaced dct[aName] = FunctionModel(aDictOfMethods[aName]) with  dct[aName] = classmethod(FunctionModel(aDictOfMethods[aName]))

Answer (score 0):

I may be completely wrong here, but surely you just want `FunctionModel` to be the parent class of `ClassModel` ?

```
class FunctionModel(object):
    attr = None
    def __call__(self):
        return self.attr

class ClassModel(FunctionModel):
    pass
```

Now `ClassModel` will have all the attributes of `FunctionModel` but beware of over-riding stuff. When creating an `__init__` method for `ClassModel` you can make sure you call `FunctionModel`s `__init__` too with a `super()`

```
class ClassModel(FunctionModel):

    def __init__(self, extra_args):
        super(ClassModel, self).__init__()

        self.extra_args = extra_args
```

More information on python classes and inheritance [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).